# Oracle APEX Get classic report column value APEX_APPLICATION.G_F30(i) but gives ORA-01403: no data found

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

Classic report SQL:

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(10,Q.QUESTIONID) QUESTIONID_HID,
Q.QUESTION,
CASE WHEN Q.ANSWER_TYPE = 'RADIO' THEN
    CASE (SELECT LISTAGG(A.ANSWER_CODE, ', ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.ANSWERID, A.ANSWER_CODE) ANSWER
          FROM XYZ A
          WHERE A.QUESTIONID = Q.QUESTIONID)
         WHEN 'G, P' THEN                
          apex_item.radiogroup(20, 'G', NULL, 'Government')||'<br>'||
          apex_item.radiogroup(20, 'P', NULL, 'Private')
         WHEN 'L, H, M' THEN                
          apex_item.radiogroup(30, 'L', NULL, 'Low Income')||'<br>'||
          apex_item.radiogroup(30, 'H', NULL, 'High Income')||'<br>'||
          apex_item.radiogroup(30, 'M', NULL, 'Medium Income')
   END
        
ELSE
    APEX_ITEM.TEXT(20, NULL) 
END INPUTCOL
FROM ABC Q
WHERE Q.APPID = :APP_ID;
```

And my page level process:

```
DECLARE
V_QUESTIONID INTEGER;
V_ANSWER_OPT VARCHAR2(20);
V_ANSWER VARCHAR2(20);
V_ANSWER_TYPE VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN 

  FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F10.COUNT LOOP
      V_QUESTIONID := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F10(i);
      
      SELECT Q.ANSWER_TYPE INTO V_ANSWER_TYPE
      FROM ABC Q
      WHERE Q.QUESTIONID = V_QUESTIONID;
      IF V_ANSWER_TYPE = 'RADIO' THEN
       
          SELECT LISTAGG(A.ANSWER_CODE, ', ')
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.ANSWERID, A.ANSWER_CODE) ANSWER INTO V_ANSWER_OPT
              FROM XYZ A
              WHERE A.QUESTIONID = V_QUESTIONID;

      END IF;        
      IF V_ANSWER_OPT = 'G, P' THEN
          
          V_ANSWER := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F20(i);
      ELSIF V_ANSWER_OPT = 'L, H, M' THEN
          V_ANSWER := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F30(i);
      ELSE
          V_ANSWER := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F20(i);
      END IF;    
      
        INSERT INTO CSD_DTL  (CSDID,
                                           QUESTIONID,
                                           ANSWER,
                                           CUSTOMER_POINT)              
         VALUES(:P10_SURVEYID,
                V_QUESTIONID,
                V_ANSWER,
                10); 
         COMMIT;            
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

This code works fine for 4 rows one radio group and 3 text field but when loop goes for 5th row which have another radio group then it gives error.
Get classic report column value by APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i) this is not new for me but here in this case I used two radio group in same column but different rows with different codes one is apex_item.radiogroup(20, 'G', NULL, 'Government') and oter is
apex_item.radiogroup(30, 'M', NULL, 'Medium Income') because with same codes radio button not works, accept answer in only one.
My requirement is to take user response in selectable options in some questions & in text fields for some questions.
Please help if any one can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `APEX_ITEM.RADIO_GROUP` creates a single radio group for the entire report. It is meant for the use case where a user needs to select one row from the report. It cannot be used to create a radio group per row. As you have seen, that renders fine but you can only select a single value over the entire report. Use `APEX_ITEM.SWITH` (if only 2 values) or any of the `APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_%` functions for a per row selection.

Comment: Thanks it fulfils my requirement, just one thing I want to ask that APEX_ITEM.SWITH always shown selected until I pass NULL in value parameter for default. Can we show it unselected which prompt user to click for selection.

Comment: Not sure - functionality of the apex_item api is quite limited....